# why is so slow, .net task nest sub task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I create an asp.net webapi test application, here is my test code:

When I use the `result = index.ToString() + this.getresult().Result;`, the response time is 2s. If I use `Thread.Sleep(100); result = index.ToString();`, it only needs 200ms.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string Test()
    {
        var listName = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            listName.Add(i);
        }

        var response = Task.WhenAll(listName.Select(sendrequest)).Result;

        return string.Join(",", response);
    }

    public async Task<string> sendrequest(int index)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100); result = index.ToString();
                //result = index.ToString() + this.getresult().Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\WebService\\FelixTest\\log.txt",ex.ToString());
            }

            return result;

        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<string> getresult()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Comment: might be that you are usining a delay in your getresult method?

Comment: How are you measuring the timings? The `Delay` in your is only 100 (ms, by default), so it shouldn't take 2 seconds... BUT it might be down to how you're measuring the time it takes to run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are suffering from `ThreadPool` thread starvation. The problem lies in the line you have commented-out

```
//result = index.ToString() + this.getresult().Result;
```

By accessing the `Task.Result` property, you are causing a `Wait` on the `Task` returned from the `getresult()` method.  The Wait operation blocks the current thread from executing, which means that the next Task must be scheduled on another thread and so on. As you are starting 100 tasks all of which will block, the ThreadPool will attempt to start new managed threads to satisfy the demand, and this is a time-consuming process.

I would reorganise your code so that everything is asynchronous except for the one top-level `Test` method.  In this example I'm not sure why you need `Task.Factory.StartNew()` as the tasks are already run (at least partially) in parallel by virtue of the fact that they use the async-await pattern.  Perhaps your real-life example requires the tasks to be scheduled on a background thread?  If you don't need to use `Factory.StartNew()` I'd suggest rewriting `sendrequest` like this:-

```
public async Task<string> sendrequest(int index)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        result = index.ToString() + await this.getresult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\WebService\\FelixTest\\log.txt",ex.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you do need to use `Factory.StartNew()` you can still achieve the same thing, but the delegate you pass to `StartNew` should be marked `async`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description the difference is of 1800 milliseconds. You have a delay of 100 milliseconds in `getresult`. If we subtract that, the difference is of 1700 milliseconds. A string concatenation with `"OK"` does not explain that. As a result, you probably use a loop and the delays of 100 milliseconds in `getresult` add up to a significant wait.

Comment: hi,i update the question. add the thread.sleep(100), now response time is 200ms.

Comment: If you debug your code, how many times does it enter getresult?

Comment: 100 times, it is ok.

Comment: If it entered 100 times, then the wait in getresult added up. It waited for 100 milliseconds for the first request and then again 100 milliseconds for the second request and so on.

Comment: but i use `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, is async; and when i use Thread.Sleep(100),the response time is only 200ms.